# How to remove tap with too much tape

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

i think i've screwed this up and put too much tape on and can't for the life of me, turn it the other way round so that the tape isn't exposed so much. Anyway ideas?

[image]

Comment: How to remove *excess* PTFE tape from the threads of a pipe fitting?

Answer (score 5):

The fact that you can see the tape has no bearing on the success of the job. If it doesn't leak consider the job well done. If the exposed tape gives you worry that someone will see the tape and say it is a bad job, tell them that is how much you had to use to get a tight seal. If you really want to remove the excess tape, take a **wire brush** and carefully use it to remove the excess tape.

Comment: 'If it doesn't leak consider the job well done' - solid advice.

Comment: Not sure what a wire brush would do to the finish even if used carefully. I'd use a utility knife and gently/lightly run it around the fitting following the threads and then you can just lift the excess tape off.

Comment: @d.george many thanks, really appreciate the feedback.

Comment: A razor blade can be used to cut the tape at the join. The seal is further up so no worries. Then just unroll the extra.

Comment: If you decide to use a vise or some type of clamp, pipe wrench or other, screw a nipple into the open end of the brass fitting to give it strength to resist smashing or bending the soft brass fitting. Or just leave it alone and use a wire brush as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: If you do mess up the finish, mess up *all* the finish. It's called a *scratch finish*, like on stainless steel sinks (just use a fresh scotch brite pad). But not on that valve; it's still rough from casting, not shiny; you'd just make it look worse. But a few scratches is better than glaring white, no? or taking it back apart.... and if you can't see any tape, it doesn't pass inspection anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Expand the stuck female part with heat.**

You could try heating up the part without the handle (female part).  Start with boiling water (I worry flame will oxidize and discolor that fancy brass).  Just that female part, not the whole thing because you don't want the male part to expand.  When heated the metal will expand and grip less tightly.

Alternatively you could try the same thing with cold on the male part - shrink it down.  I had luck with dry ice for something like that once.

Comment: +1 for answering the title, but no...

Comment: @Mazura - you think it won't work, or you think I misunderstood the question?

Comment: It'll work, that's just penultimate to throwing it away.

Comment: Dipping a plumbing part in hot water is penultimate to throwing it away?  I'm not following this logic either.

Comment: If you use flame you will destroy the rubber joint inside the tap.

Answer (score 0):

easy work to undo if you own a vice, monkey wrench, or even a good set of workshop clamps... simply clamp the end and let the levarage work for you.

if you have a vice, use some wood to protect the brass from damage.

That tape has a great way of gripping the seal, but once broken, it will be easy to undo.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to unscrew it, why not check if that's needed?

The male thread on these taps is often quite long, so look into the hole...

[image]

...and check how many threads you managed to screw in. If that's enough, then, you're done.

If the female part has a separator in the middle:

[image]

...and the threads reached the separator, then there's no need to screw it in more.